# How to manage giant fixed-width file in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I have a fixed width file that is about 1200 characters wide and has about 300+ columns. I'm looking for a way to create a fixed-width data source in SSIS without using the UI for the flat file connection manager. Is there a way to modify the column definitions without having to use the UI in SSIS? I can't find a file for the data connection anywhere in the project.

Am I doomed to manually add 300+ columns into the flat-file connection manager one by one?

Comment: If you'd rather use scripting than SSIS then use BULK INSERT (a T-SQL command) or BCP.EXE (a command line tool). Both use format files which can be painful. Alternatively you could use this new BIML thing to auto generate your package. IMHO a command/T-SQL solution is easier to maintain but I've never used BIML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options come to mind. The first is to Install BIDSHelper and use the [Create Fixed Width Columns](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20Fixed%20Width%20Columns&referringTitle=Documentation)

The other, as @ElectricLlama mentioned is to use BIML. This too will require the installation of BIDS Helper but to convert a .biml file into a .dtsx [Short Walkthrough](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/06/bimlscript-overview.html)

This should approximate creating a package with a flat file connection manager (with a single column) adding a data flow and inside that consume our flat file and wire it up to a Row count. This is approximate for what you want. Just fill in the XML in the Columns tag.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Connections>
    <FlatFileConnection
        Name="FF dchess"
        FileFormat="FFF dchess"
        FilePath="C:\ssisdata\SO\Input\dchess.txt"
    />
</Connections>
<FileFormats>
    <FlatFileFormat
Name="FFF dchess"
CodePage="1252"
RowDelimiter="CRLF"
IsUnicode="false"
FlatFileType="RaggedRight"
        >
        <Columns>
            <Column Name="MyColumn" Length="08"  DataType="AnsiString"  ColumnType="FixedWidth"  CodePage="1252" />
        </Columns>
    </FlatFileFormat>
</FileFormats>
<Packages>
    <Package Name="dchess" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
        <Connections >
            <Connection ConnectionName="FF dchess" />
        </Connections>
        <Variables>
            <Variable Name="CurrentFileName" DataType="String">C:\ssisdata\so\Input\dchess.txt</Variable>
            <Variable Name="RowCountInsert" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
        </Variables>
        <Tasks>
            <Dataflow Name="DFT Load file" >
                <Transformations>
                    <FlatFileSource
                        Name="FF_SRC dchess"
                        ConnectionName="FF dchess"
                        RetainNulls="true">
                    </FlatFileSource>
                    <RowCount Name="CNT Source" VariableName="User.RowCountInsert"></RowCount>
                </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
</Packages>
</Biml>
```

Generated package looks like

[image]

Feel free to pick your jaw up off the ground ;)

Comment: The BIDSHelper method worked for me one thing to check after you do this though is to check your Header row delimiter and total row length settings as my rows were screwed up until I fixed that.